# Java Transformation to PDF

Tags: java, pdf

I am doing POC for one of my performance projects , Currently it is giving me Out Of memory Error in the current Scenario , As we have loaded that xml as DOM and then give that XSL and then transform it to PDF ,Here it gives OOMemory Error ,

After one of the comments from this forum only , I have used SAX parser for the xml file and give XSL and then use FOP for this 30 MB , System Memory is 512MB

```
System.out.println("FOP XMLTOPDFConverter\n");
            System.out.println("Preparing...");

            // Setup directories
/*          File baseDir = new File(".");
            File outDir = new File(baseDir, "out");
            outDir.mkdirs();*/

            // Setup input and output files
            File xmlfile = new File("C:/Documents and Settings/agarwgau/Desktop/300k/File_0000036357.XML");
            File xsltfile = new File("C:/Documents and Settings/agarwgau/Desktop/300k/UCB110037EventList.xsl");
            File pdffile = new File("C:/Documents and Settings/agarwgau/Desktop/300k/ResultXML2PDF.pdf");

            System.out.println("Input: XML (" + xmlfile + ")");
            System.out.println("Stylesheet: " + xsltfile);
            System.out.println("Output: PDF (" + pdffile + ")");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Transforming...");

            // configure fopFactory as desired
            FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance();

            FOUserAgent foUserAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();
            // configure foUserAgent as desired

            // Setup output
            OutputStream out = new java.io.FileOutputStream(pdffile);
            out = new java.io.BufferedOutputStream(out);

            try {
                // Construct fop with desired output format
                Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF,
                        foUserAgent, out);

                // Setup XSLT
                TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                Transformer transformer = factory
                        .newTransformer(new StreamSource(xsltfile));

                // Set the value of a <param> in the stylesheet
                transformer.setParameter("versionParam", "2.0");

                // Setup input for XSLT transformation
                Source src = new StreamSource(xmlfile);

                // Resulting SAX events (the generated FO) must be piped through
                // to FOP
                Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());

                // Start XSLT transformation and FOP processing
                transformer.transform(src, res);
            } finally {
                out.close();
            }

            System.out.println("Success!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Do you want to process the XML to some human-readable format, or just put the XML content itself into the PDF file (perhaps with syntax highlighting)?

Comment: Some HUman Readable format ?.
'<Family>

 <FathersName>Sudhir</FathersName>
 <Mother>Madhu</Mother>
 <FirstChild>Deepti</FirstChild>
 <SecondChild>Gaurav</SecondChild>
</Family>
'
After PDF it will be like this
--------------------------------
'
Father Mother  FirstChild SecondCHild

Comment: Please just [edit] your original post rather than trying to fit in a new description of the problem in comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like [Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) should be able to help you.

Comment: I have a confusion whether Apache FOP will be able to transform 25MB file into PDF, i have not started my work on this still looking after it on google

Comment: I'm not sure (and this will depend on how much RAM you have), but 25MB doesn't sound that big, especially since Apache FOP uses SAX: http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/dev/design/parsing.html#input

Comment: RAM is good on the server as per my knowledge .. as it;s a Prod. server that will get deployed ultimately ... Let me try on this FOP Thanks for this useful

Comment: I have used 30MB file for the FOP transformation to PDF but it didnot work .Please see my code in the editable format on the top

Comment: It's hard to say... Just in case you forgot, you may have to increase the memory given to the VM (e.g. using the `-Xmx` VM argument).

Comment: I have done that also till 2016 via the -Xms (min heap space) and -Xmx (max heap space) VM arguments

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices: FOP, which is an XML representation of a PDF, or iText, which creates a PDF using Java classes.

I'd recommend FOP combined with Velocity.  Make a Velocity template that represents your FO XML and map the data into it.

Comment: Let me try velocity template also Thanks